# How to avoid newlines getting removed from POST parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea

I am using a plain `textarea` for optionally marked up text in a normal POST form. Users should be able to enter double newlines to mark a new paragraph. Now the browser does send newlines (as CRLFs), but Rails replaces every newline by a single space during parameter filtering, so I can't

```
params[:lines].split '\n'
```

in my controller because it always gives me an array with one element. E.g. for an HTTP parameter with a value of `'abc%0d%0a%0d%0adef'`, `params[:lines]` is `'abc  def'` (two spaces), so I cannot detect those double line breaks. How can I avoid this specific filtering?

I am using Rails 3.1.

**Edit**: Please see my comment below for the answer - Rails has nothing to do with the problem, but my ignorance does.

Comment: that seems odd, i've never experienced this issue, could you show us your middleware stack? (output of `rake middleware`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller (with a param of: search="abc%0d%0a%0d%0adef")

```
p params.inspect
p params[:search].inspect
```

gives:

```
{"action\"=>"index", "controller"=>"my_controller", "search"=>"'abc\r\n\r\ndef'"}"
"'abc\r\n\r\ndef'"
```

That means it's coming through to the controller just fine. Where are you seeing the spaced-version? Because it'll only display as 'abc  def' if you "to-s" it.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem that the parameter gets filtered. As I mentioned, the params[:lines] list doesn't contain an HTTP-encoded string but an already filtered one (which is good), but the newlines get filtered out (which is not good). I don't want to the decoding stuff myself, Rails should do it for me.

Comment: In your controller, add the line: "puts params[:lines].inspect" and tell us what you see in the log.

Comment: Thanks, @Taryn, the `.inspect` gave me the clou. The whole thing doesn't have anything to do with HTTP and such, but the `"abc\ndef".join('\n')` is wrong - it needs double quotes to recognize the newline character, so `"abc\ndef".join("\n")` is correct. Still thinking too much in Python...